# How can I identify the current terminal emulator from a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, applescript

I've got a script that will open a new tab in the OS X Terminal application and I'm trying to add support for iTerm2.  Unfortunately, the methods to open tabs in the two terminal emulators are different.

How could I tell which of the two is being used, or is open, to conditionally run the correct script?

Comment: Do they set `$TERM` differently?

Comment: Does the "applescript" tag really apply?

Comment: I thought it might be an applescript solution since the tabbing solutions are.

Comment: @MrDaniel: Hmm, maybe.  If they did set `$TERM` differently, it might have been a solution (though I could have phrased it better).

Comment: My actual answer that arguably should have been a comment was "Do they set `$TERM` differently?"  The above comment was a comment on that answer, and it doesn't make much sense out of context.

Comment: And I see that "Do they set `$TERM` differently?" is now a comment (it's possible I didn't notice it before).  I'll probably delete most of these comments after a day or so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure how to tell iTerm and iTerm2 apart, but check the `$TERM_PROGRAM` envar. For me (Mac OS X 10.7), it returns `Apple_Terminal` for `Terminal.app`, and `iTerm.app` for iTerm2.

Comment: The $TERM_PROGRAM envar worked great -- I only really wanted to test for iTerm.app anyway and use the Terminal.app version as the default.  Thanks!

Comment: if you rung tmux, this command will return `tmux` not matter if you run it from your iterm or default apple terminal

Answer (score 5):

Working fine on Ubuntu & mint Linux--

```
ps -o comm= -p "$(($(ps -o ppid= -p "$(($(ps -o sid= -p "$$")))")))"
```

Comment: This works on my Arch + alacritty + zsh. Would be great to explain the magic further, though :)

Comment: @maricn, for further explanation see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264353/110635

Comment: Fails on macOS with zsh: `ps: sid: keyword not found\n
ps: no valid keywords; valid keywords:\n
zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at \`%cpu %mem ...'`

Comment: +1 for the kinda Lispy solution, but Bash isn't such a great Lisp, with all the quoting gotchas and all. A simpler (more Haskell-like perhaps?) way of doing it, using just plain old pipes: `$ ps -o sid= -p "$$" | xargs ps -o ppid= -p | xargs ps -o comm= -p`

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to:

```
ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: This only returns the shell they are running, NOT* the terminal emulator (e.g. xterm... )